# Prolog - Backtracking through a set of dynamic options

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I'm trying to trigger backtracking on a goal but in a dynamic way, if it's possible. To better exemplify my issue let's say we have the following PROLOG code:

```
num(1).
num(2).
num(3).
num(4).
num(5).
```

Then I head to SWI-Prolog and call: `num(X)`. This triggers backtracking looking for all solutions, by typing `;` .

What I would like is to remove those facts (`num(1)`,`num(2)`, etc) and replace that code with something thata generates those facts dynamically. Is there any way in which I can achieve this? Someting of the sorts,maybe?

```
num(X):- for X in 1..5
```

that yields the same solutions as the code above?

As far as I know, the `findall` predicate returns a list, which is not what I'm looking for. I would like to backtrack through all answers and look through them using `;` in the console.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. As far as I know, `findall` returns a list. I want to backtrack through a set of solutions using `;` in the console. Hope I explained myself well.

Comment: How about typing `member(X,[1,2,3,4,5]).` at the console.

Comment: @TomasBy Fabulous, thank you so much! That's it!

Comment: @Scott: Is this really a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, and you were already very close!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

num(X) :-
   X in 1..5.

?- num(X).
   X in 1..5.

?- num(X), X #>3.
   X in 4..5.

?- num(X), labeling([], [X]).
   X = 1
;  X = 2
;  X = 3
;  X = 4
;  X = 5.
```

Comment: That's a cannon to shoot sparrows :-P.

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog has the (non-ISO) predicate [`between/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3) for that:

```
num(X) :- between(1, 5, X).
```

You can implement the predicate (for other Prologs and for further tweaking) like this:

```
between2(A, A, A) :- !.  % green cut
between2(A, B, A) :- A < B.
between2(A, B, C) :-
    A < B,
    A1 is A + 1,
    between2(A1, B, C).
```

The signature for both `between/3` and `between2/3` is `(+From,+To,?X)`. It means that the `From` and `To` must be bound and `X` can be either bound or not. Also note that `From` and `To` must be integers such that `From <= To`. (Oh, and these integers must be written using Arabic numerals with an optional plus or minus sign before. And using ASCII. Is something non-obvious still missed? And the integers must not be too large or too small, although SWI-Prolog is usually compiled with unbounded integer support, so both `between(1, 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, X)` and `between2(1, 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, X)` usually work.)

Comment: `between(1,To,I)` succeeds for `To = 1, I = 1` only. Yet, `To = 2, I = 2, between(1,To,I)` succeeds as well. So that is not a green cut at all.

Comment: @false Have you seen the signature of `between/3` at the link provided? `From` and `To` must be bound, as they are in the question asked. You could as well complain why `between(one, two, X)` or `between(5, 1, X)` or `between(1.5, 3, X)` doesn't work "as expected".

Comment: There is no signature in your answer!

Comment: So what? It doesn't mean that the signature is `(?,?,?)`.

Comment: @false I've updated the answer. Now I wonder what other flaws you can find.